# How to instrument network calls in Xamarin.forms android on a physical device?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am looking for a way to instrument the api/network calls made in Xamarin android, so that I could log all the http request/response and header details for every api call. Can some one let me know is there any approach to do that or any Nuget available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Fiddler. The link below provide the way about how to use Fiddler to monitor network traffic from the VS Emulator for Android. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-fiddler-to-monitor-network-traffic-from-the-vs-emulator-for-android/

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, thanks for suggestion. But I would like to track the network calls on the physical android device on any network in real time.

Comment: This tool could track the network traffic on physical android device. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler

Comment: this also needs phone and the fiddler in same network, I would like to track network calls who ever installed the app from the Playstore.

Comment: I have figured out that it is not possible to instrument the API calls on runtime or compile time on a real device that should work on all the environments.

So it could be achieved by writing a wrapper for HTTPClient classes. I hope it would help if someone is looking for a similar requirement.

Thanks